# How can the content of multiple cells be copied to a single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to copy content of cells from immediate left but not a range, but selected cells into a single cell.  The cells will either have a normal number or a currency figure.

How can I do this?

I have a number in Cell A:3, a number in C:4, a number in E:5, a number in C:6; I want these numbers to be copied into a cell in Column G but on the same line. The intervening cells will have other data in, so I cannot search as a Range, rather as individual cells.

Comment: This is pretty unclear, can you give us an example?

Comment: @Raystafarian, I will try to copy an example of what I am trying to do:

Comment: Roof A  Roof B  Roof C   
Age Value Age Value Age Value All Roof Age All Roof Cost
31  £5,000       
           26  £5,000     
                   21  £5,000   
                                 31  £5,000

Comment: I have a number in Cell A:3, a number in C:4, a number in E:5, a number in C:6; I want these numbers to be copied into a cell in Column G but on the same line.  The intervening cells will have other data in, so I cannot search as a Range, rather as individual cells.  Tricky to explain, I have tried pasting a screen picture as well as pasting the cells themselves!

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/920154/edit) your question and add this information there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel the [CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function is used to combine text.

> CONCATENATE(text1, [text2], ...)

For instance, you can use a formula like `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)` to combine all the text of the individual cells into a single cell.

In the example below, the formula in `F1` combines the text from `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, and `E1`. You can reference any cell you want.

[image]

Spaces can be added with `" "`.

[image]